# Where is the mongodb stored?

Tags: nodeos, database, node

Seems my node is syncing, but so far I cannot find the mongodb and the path isn't mentioned in the docs.
Trying to setup a non-producing node to query specific incoming transactions. Using Ubuntu 16.04, full EOSIO software, no Docker.

I set :

```
mongodb-uri = mongodb://localhost:27017
```

other settings:

```
blocks-dir = "/opt/mainnet/blocks"
read-mode = read-only
validation-mode = light
mongodb-uri = mongodb://localhost:27017
mongodb-wipe = 1
mongodb-queue-size = 1024
mongodb-abi-cache-size = 2048
# mongodb-block-start = 0
mongodb-store-blocks = 1
mongodb-store-block-states = 1
mongodb-store-transactions = 1
mongodb-store-transaction-traces = 1
mongodb-store-action-traces = 1
mongodb-filter-on = *
mongodb-filter-out = eosio:onblock:
mongodb-filter-out = gu2tembqgage::
mongodb-filter-out = blocktwitter::
```

current output

```
2018-09-28T09:02:53.446 thread-1   mongo_db_plugin.cpp:438       consume_blocks       ] process_accepted_transaction, time per: 983, size: 1034, time: 1016557
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB is typically stored at `/data/db`. If it's not there, check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7247474/how-can-i-tell-where-mongodb-is-storing-data-its-not-in-the-default-data-db), [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13369795/where-is-mongo-db-database-stored-on-local-hard-drive), etc. for advice on finding the location.

edit: The database was found at `/var/lib/mongodb` as explained in the comments below.

Comment: interesting. Read this answer several times on the web, my DigitalOcean Ubuntu 16.04 machine could not find any 'data' or 'db' directory related to mongo, I checked them all using
sudo find / -name db data
And cd /data/ directory did not exist as well. Gonna check the other 2 solutions

Comment: I also found [this article](https://freestartupkits.com/articles/technology/cryptocurrency-news-and-tips/how-to-build-an-eos-application-eosio-1/) which seems to imply that mongodb is inside `~/opt/mongodb` on Linux.

Comment: indeed one of the solutions worked with this trick. Using 
$ cd ~ 
$ cd ..
$ du -hsx * | sort -rh | head -10 
on my HDD let me find /var/lib/mongodb# with 66GB currently (has not even synced half). Note, somehow it ignored my second volume at /mnt/volume2 . Double check it's not there
Please put the command and the possible paths in the answer and so I can set it as the correct answer

Comment: an addition: vi /etc/mongod.conf  and change the standard directory

Answer (score 1):

One hack is that use --dbpath armament,its the path provided externally.